# Ionic 4 clearInput icon color

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

is there a way to change the color of the clearinput icon on ionic 4 rc?

It’s a shadow dom element with .input-clear-icon class that use a background-image svg filled with this variable color: var(–ion-color-step-600,%20%23666666).

It’s rendered as a dark grey, I’m trying to make it white.

Regards

I’ve tried to override scss variable but nothing change:

```
:root {
  --input-md-input-clear-icon-color: #ffffff;
  --ion-color-step-600: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your html code?

Comment: @NathanWright the ionic view or the rendered dom?

Comment: `.input-clear-icon:before { color: red !important }` though the `!important` tag probably won't be required nor suggested since it would override things like active/hover highlights etc. Cheers :)

Comment: @user1763784 the rendered dom please. Ideally, you want to create a custom css class and add that class to your desired element on the your ionic view as to not override the defaults.

Comment: has been confirmed as a bug: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/17168